# Codeigniter update from query within controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation, controller

Hope I can explain this properly...

I am using form validation with Codeigniter.
If my form returns a string id back to the controller, how can I use this to perform a database query and use the result array to perform an update...

Does that make sense?

```
function form($id) {
    if ($this->form_validation->run('') == false) {
        //...
    }
    else {
        // Query database where strId = $this->input->post('strId')
        // Put results into an array called $data
        // Update database where id = $this->input->post('id')

        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('database', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use a model to perform database related actions, also where are you stuck? you know how to make queries and I assume you know how to get the results, just implement a function in a model following the pseudo code you provided

Comment: I do. So if I end my function in model with                                 return $query->result_array();, load it in the controller as $data['query'] - is my update line $this->db->update('database', $data['query']);? It's the UPDATE line I'm stuck on I suppose... @koala_dev

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
    //... (if valid) ...
    $this->load->model('myform'); //loads myform_model.php
    $this->myform->update(); //call the update method
```

Model (myform_model.php):

```
    function update(){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
        $this->db->update('tableName', $data);
    }
```

Note: Your id must already exist in the database table since you're using "update". To insert data, use $this->db->insert();

Answer (score 1):

nice code excellent :

function update($id, $data)  {

```
    $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('$id'));
    $this->db->update('tableName', $data);
}
```

or lik this:

function update($id, $data)  {

```
    $this->db->where('id', '$id');
    $this->db->update('tableName', $data);
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe what where this code should be set and how it could help the OP?